# C++ Checking if a user input is the same as the name of a queue

Tags: c++, class, vector, queue

I have a vector of queues named `p` and the number of queues is input by the user.

```
vector<queue<datatype>> p;
```

Let's say the user wants to check the inputs of `p4`, but forgot he only entered 3 queues. How would I check it?

Comment: Not what I meant. The user inputs p4 and I have to check if there are 4 queues, but the problem is that the user is not inputting an integer, but a string.

Comment: Then you'll have to remove the 'p' and convert it to an int. But why? Why not just have the user input an integer? You might be suffering from the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Use a map instead of a vector? Parse the string into an integer?

Comment: It's stated in the project assignment.

Comment: You want to access the `p[3]` when user inputs `p4`? You can use either `std::map` or create a function that will take number from user input.

Comment: The user inputs "p1" as a string and it has to be "p1". How would i separate "p1" into 'p' and the int 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
string x;
int y;
cin >> x;
y = x[1];
if(y == p.size())
```